# Email verification link using PHPmailer

Tags: phpmailer

I am trying to send out an email verification message with a link the user can click on, using phpmailer. However, when I include the URL it causes problems.

I've done a bit of troubleshooting and it appears to the the URL which causes the problem.

The code I have at the moment is:

```
$mail->Body    = '
<p>We have recevied a registration request from this account. Please
use the following link to verify your email. If you did not attempt to register,
please ignore this email.</p>
<p><a href="' . $url . '">' . $url . '</a></p>';
$mail->AltBody = 'Welcome to the site, click on this link' . ;

$mail->send();
```

An example link is:

```
https://www.....co.uk/verifyemail.php?selector=aa2a233b3bb03a75&validator=ec4545a89cb1a9f3814f0e4d3f142f60fa14ebd9cbf3911a301b03756ab59b66
```

After the above code, I have the following:

```
header('Location: ../index.php?result=unverified');
exit();
```

If I run the code as above, the email is sent correctly, but instead of going back to the loading page, it just shows a page with all the communication between the server and the hosting server.

If I take out the 'AltBody' bit, it sends correctly and goes to index.html correctly.

If I take out all the URLs, it sends the email correctly and goes to index.html correctly.

Do I need to escape the URL somehow? Or am I missing something else?

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Double check what is in `$url`, don't assume. Also try using a fixed string instead of the variable, just to eliminate possibilities. generally with debugging, debug one thing at a time - disable the redirect until you've confirmed the rest is working.

Comment: The url is generated using 'bin2hex(random_bytes())' for the selector and the validator. I started off with a Body and an AltBody, both with the URL and it sent the email, but it just didn't move on through the code, as though it was waiting for something. It didn't throw up any error messages that I could see. Either taking out the 'AltBody' line, or taking out the urls solves the problem, but means I either have to do without the non-html email, or I can't include the URL.

Comment: `random_bytes` can hang up waiting for entropy. This was exactly my point - **Don't assume** that your code is doing what you *think* it should; **check it**, and test using static values, so you're only testing one thing at a time. Right now for example you're testing two things at once - trying to diagnose your random string function by using email. *One thing at a time*!